# Why can't Typescript infer method call when an argument to a function is an object with said method whose inputs are properties on the object?

Tags: typescript

Why isn't Typescript smart enough to figure out that the example below can't have an error in practice:

```
interface M1 {
  props: {
    color: 'red' | 'blue';
    transparency: 0 | 1;
  },
  f: (props: M1['props']) => string
}

interface M2 {
  props: {
    age: number;
    country: string;
  },
  f: (props: M2['props']) => string
} 

const myFunc = (param: M1 | M2) => {
  return param.f(param.props)
}
```

`myFunc`'s parameter will either be M1 or M2, but not both; so whichever it is, when you call `param.f(params.props)`, you know that `params.props` is of the same type as the input of `param.f`.

Is this logic incorrect or why can't TS infer this?

Comment: Maybe because string is undefined?

Comment: You’d have to type guard param. At any point in the method, param can be either M1 or M2, unless you use a conditional that rules one of them out or type guards one of them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to work around that limitation would be to create a superinterface `M`, and define the method on `M` using a [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types):

```
interface M { 
  props: { [name: string]: any };
  f: (props: this['props']) => string;
}

interface M1 extends M {
  props: {
    color: 'red' | 'blue';
    transparency: 0 | 1;
  }
}

interface M2 extends M {
  props: {
    age: number;
    country: string;
  }
} 

const myFunc = (param: M) => {
  return param.f(param.props);
}
```